# How to create path that includes arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, arc, tikz-path

I'm trying to make something like this in one command:
[image: Fig1]

I'm doing this via this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \fill[blue] plot[smooth, left] coordinates  {(1,0) (0,0)  (0,1)}; 
    \fill[blue] (0,0) -- (1,0) arc (0:90:1) -- (0,0); % Q-Line
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And if I moving the `Q-Line` this what I get:
[image: Fig2]

My question is: if there is  any option to make the first figure but in **one command**? i.e. to put in `\fill[blue] plot[smooth, left] coordinates  {(1,0) (0,0)  (0,1)}` arc? (or other way if this possible).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \fill[blue] plot[smooth] coordinates  {(0,1) (0,0)  (1,0)} arc (0:90:1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle with area filled]

The `arc( : : )` notation is discouraged, but it does work. Here is the correct way to write it:

```
\fill[blue] plot[smooth] coordinates  {(0,1) (0,0)  (1,0)} arc[start angle=0, end angle=90, radius=1] ;
```

Comment: Since when is `arc( : : )` discouraged? The current manual states, that „this syntax is harder to read, so the normal syntax should be preferred in general“. It does not mention that this notation is deprecated.

Comment: Yes - what it says in the manual.

Comment: So, then I obviously misunderstood you because of the „still“ in your statement above. I first read it in a temporal sense so I thought you meant deprecated. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Ok - I understand. My english could be better.

Comment: No, it‘s fine! Sorry, maybe it’s just too late for me =D