# Length of an arc diagram in radians

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc, degrees

I am trying to create a homework assignment and I want to draw some circles with the radius and angle labeled. The following code can draw a circle with radius 5 and 120 degree angle.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\sffamily\Large]
\draw (0,0) circle (5cm);
\draw[very thick,fill=blue!30] (0,0) --  (120:5) arc(120:0:5) -- cycle;
\draw[latex-latex]  (120:1.2) arc(120:0:1.2) node[above=5pt, midway]{$120^{\circ}$};
\draw[very thick,-latex] (0,0) --  (0:5) node[midway,below=2pt]{$5$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: The result from the above code]

My question is: is there a way to do the same thing but with radian inputs instead? I figured out a way to do pi/2 but it doesn't work for something like 5pi/4.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `deg(5*pi/4)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `deg()` function to convert radians to degrees. So, `deg(5*pi/4)` would result in `225`.

Note that the `arc` and `circle` syntax you used is discouraged. With the newer syntax and `deg(5*pi/4)`, your diagram would look like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, font=\sffamily\Large]
    \draw (0,0) circle[radius=5];
    \draw[very thick, fill=blue!30] 
        (0,0) -- ({deg(5*pi/4)}:5) 
        arc[start angle={deg(5*pi/4)}, end angle=0, radius=5] -- cycle;
    \draw[latex-latex] 
        ({deg(5*pi/4)}:1.2) 
        arc[start angle={deg(5*pi/4)}, end angle=0, radius=1.2] 
        node[above=5pt, midway] {$225^{\circ}$};
    \draw[very thick, -latex] (0,0) -- (0:5) 
        node[midway, below=2pt]{$5$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And because I totally like `\pic`s:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/circle with segment/.style 2 args={
        code={
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=#2];
            \draw[pic actions] 
                (0,0) -- ({deg(#1)}:#2) 
                arc[start angle={deg(#1)}, end angle=0, radius=#2] -- cycle;
            \draw[<->] 
                ({deg(#1)}:1.2) 
                arc[start angle={deg(#1)}, end angle=0, radius=1.2] 
                node[midway, shift={({deg(#1)/2}:15pt)}] {
                    \pgfmathparse{deg(#1)}
                    $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}^{\circ}$
                };
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0:#2) 
                node[midway, below=2pt]{
                    \pgfmathparse{#2}
                    $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$
                };
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, >=latex, font=\sffamily\Large]

\pic[fill=blue!30] {circle with segment={5*pi/4}{5}};

\pic[fill=red!30] at (10,0) {circle with segment={pi/2}{3}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And a (probably not optimal) solution for a label showing radians:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% transforms any number of the form x, x*pi, pi/x or x*pi/y 
% into properly styled math-mode
% where x and y can be any number, with or without decimal separator (dot)
\seq_new:N \l_topifrac_temp_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\topifrac}{ m }{
    \regex_extract_once:nnN { \A(\d*\.?\d+)?(\*?pi)?(/(\d*\.?\d+))?\Z } 
        { #1 } \l_topifrac_temp_seq
    \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 2 }
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 5 } } 
        { \tl_if_blank:eTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 3 } }  
            { }
            { \pi }
        }
        { \frac{\pi}{ \seq_item:Nn \l_topifrac_temp_seq { 5 } } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{
    pics/circle with segment/.style 2 args={
        code={
            \draw (0,0) circle[radius=#2];
            \draw[pic actions] 
                (0,0) -- ({deg(#1)}:#2) 
                arc[start angle={deg(#1)}, end angle=0, radius=#2] -- cycle;
            \draw[<->] 
                ({deg(#1)}:1.2) 
                arc[start angle={deg(#1)}, end angle=0, radius=1.2] 
                node[midway, shift={({deg(#1)/2}:15pt)}] {
                    $\topifrac{#1}$
                };
            \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0:#2) 
                node[midway, below=2pt]{
                    \pgfmathparse{#2}
                    $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$
                };
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, >=latex, font=\sffamily\Large]

\pic[fill=blue!30] {circle with segment={5*pi/4}{5}};

\pic[fill=red!30] at (10,0) {circle with segment={pi/2}{3}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect. One last question, I am also trying to create a new command with 2 inputs: radius and radian. I got everything to work with the command but when I compile the radian value prints out as pi/4 (for example) instead of the actual pi symbol divide by 4. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Yahya I can imagine what you mean. But maybe it is best to ask a new question, because I cannot currently think of a simple solution for this.

Comment: Will do! thanks a lot

Comment: @JasperHabicht: I was not aware the shortened arc syntax `arc(⟨start angle⟩:⟨end angle⟩:⟨radius⟩)` was deprecated. Is that documented somewhere? It still appears in the manual in section 14.7.

Comment: @SandyG Yes, it also works, but it is recommended to use the newer syntax, as far as I know. It is not explicitly stated that the shorter syntax is deprecated, but I read it like this as the manual suggests that the other syntax is preferable.

Comment: @SandyG I eventually found a discussion I had earlier on this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650358/47927 (in the comments). So, probably "discouraged" is a better choice of words then ... I'll change this in my post.